# Some problems with camera rotations and object rotations in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make the object rotate with the camera my code for the rotation currently looks like this:

```
function update() {
  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(update)
  movement();

  var test = camera.getWorldRotation();

    player.rotation.y = test.y


}
```

I can only rotate the object 45 degrees to the left and to the right then the player rotation stops rotating while the camera can keep on rotating.

Comment: What kind of camera do you use?

Comment: I am using the perspectivecamera